# Check specific characters in String by order

Tags: python

Hello every one I have a question about checking string, I want to check the specific characters in the word by orders

```
Ah = "a","h","i"
Oo= "o", "y","wh"


text = "whats going on my friend?"
text_splited = text.split()
for word in text_splited:
    print "Checking this :",word
    for ph in Ah:
       if ph in word:
          print ph
    for ph in Oo:
       if ph in word:
          print ph
```

The result is com out like this :

```
Checking this : whats
a
h
wh
Checking this : going
i
o
Checking this : on
o
Checking this : my
y
Checking this : friend?
Lip  : i
```

for example "whats" the expected result is the  "wh","h","a"   (in order) 
anyone can help, please :)

Thanks

Comment: is differentiating between `Ah` and `Oo` important?

Comment: yes, i trying to make a word recognition  Ah is a "Ah"mouth shape, "Oo" is a "O"shape

Comment: your output does not reflect that differentiation though..

Comment: You could use a Regex

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care the mixing of the elements of `Oo` and `Ah`. This might works:

```
Ah = "a","h","i"
Oo= "o", "y","wh"


text = "whats going on my friend?"
text_splited = text.split()
for word in text_splited:
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    print("Checking this :",word)
    for ph in Ah:
        list1.append((word.find(ph),ph)) #to preserve the index of element

    list2.extend(list1)
    for ph in Oo:
        list2.append((word.find(ph),ph)) #to preserve the index of element
    list2.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])
    for i in list2:
          if(i[0]>=0):
            print(i[1])
```

we are just printing the found elements in sorted order.
Output of above code is:

```
Checking this : whats
wh
h
a
Checking this : going
o
i
Checking this : on
o
Checking this : my
y
Checking this : friend?
i
```